# cannot target specific element in page

Tags: jquery

I am using 2 plugins: *[gallerific](http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/index.html)* and *[powerzoomer](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/powerzoomer.htm)* that work ok with one another up until I am trying to target a specific element from the gallery.

The powerzoomer initializes like this and works for various images (example [here](http://agencia.ro/gallery/1/)):

```
$('img').addpowerzoom({
defaultpower: 2,
powerrange: [2,0],
largeimage: null,
magnifiersize: [150,150]
})
```

However if I try to target the img from the big preview (like in [this example](http://agencia.ro/gallery/1/index2.html)) it is not working. I do it like this:

```
$('#slideshow img').addpowerzoom({
defaultpower: 2,
powerrange: [2,0],
largeimage: null,
magnifiersize: [150,150]
})
```

The *gallerific* plugin creates upon initialization code that looks like this:

```
<div id="slideshow" class="slideshow">
<span class="image-wrapper current" style="opacity: 1; ">
<a class="advance-link" rel="history" href="#img4" title="your image title">&nbsp;
<img alt="your image title" src="images/image(3).jpg">
</a>
</span>
</div>
```

However I understand that the powerzoomer initializes on *jQuery(document).ready* which means that it is not going to apply any of the properties of this plugin if the code is changed inside the elements of the document.

To conclude: do you have any idea of how can I make the powerzoomer work for the big image from the gallery?

**EDIT (solution):**

in the file that creates the gallery *jquery.galleriffic.js* at line 633 there is a new function that creates the new slide that contains the image that I was targeting:

```
newSlide.find('a')
.append(imageData.image)
.click(function(e) {
gallery.clickHandler(e, this);
});
```

After this I added:

```
newSlide.find('img').addpowerzoom({
defaultpower: 2,
powerrange: [2,0],
largeimage: null,
magnifiersize: [150,150]
})
```

which creates what I needed: adds the zoom plugin to the main image.

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at the powerzoomer js...it directly scans for only images. Hence if you want to make it work for the big images. Try using

```
$('#slideshow').find('img').addpowerzoom({
defaultpower: 2,
powerrange: [2,0],
largeimage: null,
magnifiersize: [150,150]
})
```

Comment: I just tried and it is not working. However I do not understand why isn't it finding the big image when it searches for img elements.

Comment: glad that you got the solution :)